# Jquery on-screen input-to-output: parsing newlines into CR \n howto?

Tags: jquery, html

The code I have now is very simplistic:

```
// JS doc
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#id_input").keyup(function(e) {
        var val = $("#id_input").val();
        $("#id_output").val(val);
    });

});
```

I'm trying to improve it such that pressing shift+enter and getting a newline in my input results in a newline in my output.  As it is, there's a newline in the code, I think, but there's no `\n`, which is the desired output for ctrl+enter in the input.

http://jsfiddle.net/hD8CF/3/

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to get new lines to show as breaks [nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

Comment: Really? Did I miss the [tag:php] tag?

Comment: What if you try with <pre> tags?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hD8CF/10/ puts the `<pre>` tag into the equation.

The key line change is here:
`$("#id_output").html("<pre>" + val + "</pre>");`

Another comment mentions adding `<pre></pre>` to the HTML and targeting that for the output.

You can see a working draft of that on jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/fqX8c/.  Please like his comment, above.  Also, I have code that sends the text as an object, on defocus, which is useful in other ways; unfortunately for me, it uses knockback, and I use jQuery and mooTools.  I'll be trying to translate it to jQuery.  http://jsfiddle.net/hD8CF/18/, *working version*: http://jsfiddle.net/hD8CF/20/: *educational version*